# How to recreate Iterator within ListIterator? ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrentmodificationexception

I have `ListIterator` and within it there is `list2.iterator()` which throws `ConcurrentModificationException` when 2nd iteration goes through `ListIterator`

```
    ExecutorService executorService  = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            1,       // Initial pool size
            1,       // Max pool size
            1,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
    );
    while(true){
       executorService.execute(() -> {                              
           List<String> list = Storage.list;
           for (ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator(); listIterator.hasNext(); ) {
               String s = listIterator.next();
               // string modification
               listIterator.set(s);
               List<String> list2 = Storage.list2;
               // calling list2.iterator(); on 2nd iteration of listIterator throws ConcurrentModificationException
               for (Iterator<String> iter2 = list2.iterator(); iter2 .hasNext(); ) {
                   String s2 = list2.next();
                   // no modifications of list2
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

`list1` and `list2` are created as `sublist()` of another List.
How to avoid this exception and recreate list2 `Iterator` for 2nd iteration?

Comment: Can you show how you are modifying the list?

Comment: In the body of the inner loop, you are modifying `list2`. The solution is.. not to do that. CoModEx means: Something changed the underlying list during iteration. If you must, either 'cache' the changes you want to make and do them after, or use CopyOnWriteList, or make the changes on the (list)iterator (e.g. call `iterator.remove()`, do not call `list.remove(idx)`.

Comment: I am not modyfing list2, but the ConcurrentModificationException is thrown. I could use casual for each loop, but for that is also thrown ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: What does the body of the inner loop do? Could list2 be modified concurrently from another thread? I think we’ll need a minimal, reproducible example to be able to answer definitively.

Comment: It shouldn't be and it's not.

Comment: What is `requirementsListIterator`? It is used, but never defined in the example.

Comment: It's indeed listIterator.

Comment: Are you sure the `while` is correct? You are nonstop and endlessly submitting tasks for execution.

Comment: The while is shown as example here and it was not the problem.

Comment: You should post code that reproduces the problem, not some pseudocode. There's lots of edits and the snippet still wouldn't even compile (`list2.next()`, `Storage` is missing etc.).

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` are sublists, they are still backed by the original list. Modifications of any of those lists (the original and its sublists) will be seen as concurrent modification of all of those lists.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this I ended up extending `list2.sublist();` with list recreation, adding `.stream().toList()`. As I don't need `Iterator` for this solution I exchanged it for each loop. It seems that there is problem with iteration on `List` created by method `sublist()` within `ListIterator`.

Comment: `sublist` does _not_ create a new list. It is a _view_ on the original list. Modifying the sublist will modify the original list (and vice-versa).

Comment: Using `.stream().toList()` is inefficient, use `new ArrayList(...)` to create a copy of the sublist to a new list.